# How do I access a string request?

Tags: java, vert.x

I have a http server in java vert.x and I get a request from the client with a string and I need to save this string in the variable How do I access the string that is sent ?

```
public class Server extends AbstractVerticle {
    private Router router;
    private HttpServer httpServer = null;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
        httpServer.requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(HttpServerRequest request) {
                System.out.println("incoming request!");
                Buffer fullRequestBody = Buffer.buffer();
                if (request.method() == HttpMethod.POST) {
                    request.handler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(Buffer buffer) {
                            fullRequestBody.appendBuffer(buffer);
                        }
                    });
                    request.bodyHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(Buffer buffer) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        httpServer.listen(9999);
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please share your source code?

Comment: Welcome yerucham! Please use the [edit] button to add additional details to your question, not the answer box.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Server extends AbstractVerticle {
private Router router;
private HttpServer httpServer = null;

@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
    httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
    httpServer.requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServerRequest request) {
            System.out.println("incoming request!");
            Buffer fullRequestBody = Buffer.buffer();
            if (request.method() == HttpMethod.POST) {
                request.handler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Buffer buffer) {
                        fullRequestBody.appendBuffer(buffer);
                    }
                });
                request.bodyHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Buffer buffer) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    httpServer.listen(9999);
}
```

}